# Magnolia app which runs in frame

Tags: magnolia

I'd like to create a magnolia app which will show content from extra page in the frame. I think it's possible, but cannot find any example how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible. What you are looking for is creation of custom app using `EmbeddedPageSubApp`. More details at [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Choose+the+right+app+type)

If you want simple example, try to import and start [this app](https://gist.github.com/593b1efb92452dbe66df4b72af66f3dd). It should start simple JS game within your subapp.

Remember that any page you try to load in iframe will need to use same protocol as the main Magnolia app does or browser will most likely block it. In the example I gave, it would work only over `http`, but not over `https`, if you want to show something while people are connecting to your Magnolia over https, you would need to set `url` to be https too.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: I was waiting for your answer )) Thank you Jan. It works fine.